# Force focus client under mouse

Tags: awesome-wm

There are recipes on how to change focus on mouse move or client change.
But what I want, is to prevent any window from stealing focus. E.g. I open a new terminal via the default `meta-Enter` shortcut, and when it opens it immediately steals focus. Is there any way to prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Focus events can happen in many ways. In the case of the new clients, just comment the `focus` line in your rules.

For the focus follow mouse, remove the `client.focus = c` in the `mouse::enter` section of `rc.lua`

For specific clients, you can add focus filters:

https://awesomewm.org/apidoc/libraries/awful.ewmh.html#add_activate_filter

For the deepest and most advanced focus control, you can disconnect the default focus handler (`awful.ewmh.activate`) from the `request::activate` (Awesome 4.0+) signal and implement your own. In that case, you will have absolute control over every focus events.

Comment: Strange, commenting out `focus` line in the rules didn't change anything. But adding a filter via `add_activate_filter` that always returns false did the trick. Thanks!